# android studio bundle or sdk only

Tags: android, updates

I am using Android Studio 1.3 and it suggest to me to upgrade to 1.4.

Should i download the 1.1gb bundle or just the 300mb sdk or 350mb zip?

And what is the difference between having the bundle and only the sdk. Is it enough for me to just download sdk? I just want that update they have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry so much, just follow these steps to upgrade to the latest version of Android Studio.

Through Android Studio:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on Configure
3. Click on Check for Update
4. The system will suggest updates to the platform and plugins, if necessary.
5. Continues to other steps

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: Thank you very much, I just clicked Help then pressed "c" then selected update.